# how to get first page of docx file with POI apache?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I'm creating a application with java and poi apache.
I want to use only the first page of docx file.
how to get only the first page of docx file with POI apache?

Comment: Where is the code sample which you tried. Avoid asking a question straightaway before attempting yourself or atleast going through the material on the net. There are tons of material related to Apache POI on net which will guide you to what you want to do over here.

Comment: Are you aware that the Word file format, unlike something such as PDF, isn't a page based format?